# left join on same table in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to write following query in sequelize but Not able to understand how to do.

`SELECT * FROM RegisterUser AS RegisterUser 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Notification as Noti ON PM_UserID = Noti.ReceiveID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN RegisterUser AS RegisterUser1 ON 
 Noti.SenderId = RegisterUser1.PM_UserID
 WHERE RegisterUser.PM_UserID = ReceiveID`

I have written below query as a single left join and it works fine.

```
  RegisterUser.findAll({
include: [
  {
    model: Notification,
    as: 'NotificationrecipientId',
    required: false,
  },
],
raw: true });
```

And my assciotion is as follow:

```
db.RegisterUser.hasMany(db.Notifications, { as: 'NotificationrecipientId', foreignKey: 'ReceiveID' });
```

Sender ID as well in Register User table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you have define one more association :

```
db.Notification.belongsTo(db.RegisterUser, { as: 'Sender', foreignKey: 'SenderId' });
```

and then use it like :

```
RegisterUser.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Notification,
        as: 'NotificationrecipientId',
        required: false,
        include: [{
            model: RegisterUser,
            as: 'Sender', // <---- HERE
            required: false,
        }, ]
    }, ],
    raw: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it Works.

Comment: helpful solution