# How can I do self join in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a Participation Model having two atributes: `cid` for conversation id and `uid` for user id.

And I have this query:

```
SELECT tA.cid
FROM participation tA, participation tB
WHERE tA.uid = "aaa" AND tB.uid = "aab" AND tA.cid = tB.cid;
```

It will return the id of the conversation in which both users are participating - only the conversation includes both users.

Edited: The Conversation Model and the User Model have the *belongs-To-Many* association through the Participation Model.

So how can I do the query in Sequelize? Can I use `include`?

```
participation.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: participation
  }]

  //Other options...
})
```

Comment: Please check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53592051/2349407

Comment: No, it's not my case.

Comment: Yes it is, you still need to do the association on the table itself before you can do the query.

Comment: What type of association do I need? And is there any solution if I don't want to do the association on the table itself?

Answer (score 1):

An include would be used if you had the IDs joined through a separate model defined with "has many" or "belongs to many" relationship. Then you could try something like:

```
conversation.findAll({
      where: {
      [Op.and]: [{uid: "aaa"}, {uid: "aab"}]
      include: [{
        model: user,
        through: {
          attributes: ["uid", "cid"]
        }
      }]
    })


Otherwise you could try something like this:

participation.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.and]: [{uid: "aaa"}, {uid: "aab"}]
  }
});
```

Comment: The Conversation Model and the User Model have the belongs-To-Many association through the Participation Model. And your second solution will return nothing.